# Ending child process with return 0

Tags: c, fork

Is `return 0` in `case 0` the correct choice? In other words, does `return 0` call the `_exit()` function? Or maybe it calls `exit()`, hence this code is unsafe?

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello_fork! (PID=%lu)\n", (unsigned long)getpid());
    pid_t pid = fork();
    switch(pid){
        case -1: perror("fork"); return 1;

        case 0: printf("child: PID=%lu\n", (unsigned long)getpid());
        return 0;

        default: printf("parent: PID=%lu\n\n", (unsigned long)getpid()); 
        if(wait(NULL)<0) 
            perror("wait");
        printf("THE END\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `return` from the `main` function is equivalent to calling `exit`.

From section 5.1.2.2.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with
>   `int`, a return from the initial call to the `main` function is
>   equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned  by 
>   the `main` function  as  its  argument

Because you're exiting from a child process, you should explicitly call `_exit` instead.